# Properly sort an NSString array including words starting with a dash or special symbols (for a dictionary)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to iOS and am trying to build a dictionary app. I have an `NSMutableDictionary` of words and definitions, whose words (the keys) I keep in a separate `NSArray` of `NSStrings` called `sortedWords`.

```
sortedWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[entries allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
```

As you can see, I'm doing a case-insensitive compare for every key as I should in a dictionary. However, a recent database update included new words in my dictionary which are mere suffixes that begin with a dash. These entries now precede all entries that begin with letter A and are listed in alphabetical order.

What I want to achieve is to keep the alphabetical ordering of all the entries even the suffixes, but make the suffixes the first entries of every letter. For example, for `E`, the order of entries would be:

```
-er
-est
each
eager
eagle
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @manecosta's answer. The complete solution is rather complicated, though:

```
#define hasDash hasPrefix:@"-"
// ...

NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"-con", @"baby",
    @"context", @"zebra", @"-ar", @"-am", @"Big", @"chastity",
    @"-b", @"American", @"brute"]];

[arr sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *s1, NSString *s2) {
    if (![s1 hasDash] && ![s2 hasDash]) {
        return [s1 caseInsensitiveCompare:s2];
    } else if ([s1 hasDash] && [s2 hasDash]) {
        NSString *c1 = [s1 substringFromIndex:1];
        NSString *c2 = [s2 substringFromIndex:1];
        return [c1 caseInsensitiveCompare:c2];
    } else if ([s1 hasDash]) {
        NSString *c1 = [s1 substringFromIndex:1];
        if ([[[c1 substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]
             isEqualToString:[[s2 substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]]) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else {
            return [c1 caseInsensitiveCompare:s2];
        }
    } else { // if ([s2 hasDash]) {
        NSString *c2 = [s2 substringFromIndex:1];
        if ([[[s1 substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]
             isEqualToString:[[c2 substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString]]) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return [s1 caseInsensitiveCompare:c2];
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask for a sort using your own comparator. Your comparator basically removes the - preffix and then compares both strings. Something like this:

```
[sortedWords sortUsingComparator:^(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {

    NSString *temp1 = obj1;
    NSString *temp2 = obj2;
    if ([obj1 hasPrefix:@"-"])
         temp1 = [obj1 substringFromIndex:1];
    if ([obj2 hasPrefix:@"-"])
         temp2 = [obj2 substringFromIndex:1];

    return [temp1 caseInsensitiveCompare:temp2];
}];
```

I didn't test this code but it should serve as a guide at least!

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own comparison function, and work your magic as you please

Somewhere in your class add this c++ looking method

```
NSInteger sortStrings(id value1, id value2, void *context); // This is just to avoid a warning when compiling the project :)

NSInteger sortStrings(id value1, id value2, void *context) {

    ... value1 and value2 will be NSStrings, compare them however you want ....

    returning -1 will mean value1 should come before
    returning 1 will mean value2 should come before
    returning 0 will mean they are equal and it won't matter which one is first

}
```

To do the sorting, do this:

```
[array sortUsingFunction:sortStrings context:nil];
```

**EDIT**

You can pass whatever you want in `context:` and it will be available to you in the function in the `context` object, in case you need any environment variable or something

When doing the sorting, the array also needs to be an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own algorithm to compare using the code below.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id o1, id o2) {
            NSString *string1 = (NSString *)o1;
            NSString *string2 = (NSString *)o2;

            return [string1 compare:string2];
        }];
```